# IE9 breaks my ActiveX WebBrowser code

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-9, powerbuilder

I'm using the WebBrowser control embedded in a window in a PowerBuilder application. Part of that use is for mail merge, where I load a document with Navigate(url, ...), then wait for the DocumentComplete (with ReadyState equals 4, i.e. Complete).

After that, I want to get the document's body, to change it some and then print it. But that document.body comes up as null, meaning it isn't really loaded yet. If I break in a debugger, or put in a MessageBox before trying to get the body, it's always OK.

This worked fine in IE8, without needing any break or anything.

I've tried adding in Yield() calls, sleeping for a few seconds, etc., but none of that helps.

I'm also on a 64-bit Windows 7 computer, not sure whether or not that is relevant.

Any bright ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK. It turns out that in my DocumentComplete event, I was setting DesignMode to On. That is required when I'm merging one document and then letting the user edit it, But when I was doing an email mail merge, and merging, printing to PDF and then emailing one document after another, it was not necessary.

In IE8 and earlier versions, it caused no problems. But in IE9, it for some reason caused the document.body to be null, unless or until I did something like a break in the debugger or a MessageBox. Since that wasn't appropriate in that email merge process, I just coded things so I didn't set DesignMode to On in that situation, and everything is OK now.